# How to make two elements appear and disappear on a top of each other in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I trying to make header one disappear, then header two appear and disappear and header one appear in a loop. The problem with my code is, that header two appears only for very short amount of time and empty screen follows for at least 2-3 seconds before header one appears.

JS:

```
var h1 = $('.header_one');
var h2 = $('.header_two');

setInterval(function(){
    h1.fadeOut(1000);
    h2.fadeIn(1000);
    h2.fadeOut(2000, function() { h1.fadeIn(); });
}, 4000);
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class="header_one"> HEADER ONE </h1>
<h2 class="header_two"> HEADER TWO </h2>
```

CSS:

```
h1, h2 {
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}     

h2 {display: none;}
```

There is also a problem: when header two disappears, my two links underneath h1 and h2, that are set to position: relative; move to the top of the page.

Comment: i belive is better the use of animate, for thois type of things in jquery

Comment: Why, if you don't mind explaining, Alvaro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it: [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/6rkx7f77/)

```js
$("#box1").hide();


function animate() {
  $("#box2").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $("#box1").fadeIn(1000, function() {
      $("#box1").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $("#box2").fadeIn(1000, animate);
      });
    });
  });
}

animate();
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1"></div>
<div id="box2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your links are moving up when the headers disappear is because the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` are manipulating the `display` property which removes it from the flow of the document. Only the `visibility` property would retain the element's position and reserve the space for it.

Assuming that your 2 headers look the same in terms of styling, why not use just one and change the text inside it while animating the color/transparency?

But if you really want to fire them in sequence given your code then you need to do what you did on the last line, where one is a callback when the other finishes; however, this won't fix your links moving up problem.

This is a really nasty/bad way of doing it, but it works...

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('h1').fadeOut(function(){
        $('h2').fadeIn();
    });
}, 4000);

setInterval(function(){
    $('h2').fadeOut(function(){
        $('h1').fadeIn();
    });
}, 8000);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is my option to do a loop with jquery [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

https://jsfiddle.net/vbw8jLko/

```
var h1 = $('.header_one');
var h2 = $('.header_two');

function loop(){
console.log('llop');
    $( ".header_one" ).stop().css('opacity', 0).show().animate({opacity:1}, 700).delay(700).animate({
    opacity: 0
  }, 1000, function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $( ".header_two" ).stop().css('opacity', 0).show().delay(100).animate({
    opacity: 1
  }, 1000).delay(700).animate({opacity:0}, 1000, function(){
  $(this).hide(); loop()});
  });

}

loop();
```

Expect like it :)